# How to pass value of a character to another .bat file in c?

Tags: c, batch-file

i was trying to make a program which calls an batch file by giving it a parameter. the main error is i am not able to pass/send the value/string of character to the batch file. when i run it displays the name of the char(or whatever it is called) but i want it to display the string stored in that char.
the source code of the c program is:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(char a)
{
    a="hello sir";
    system("batch.bat a");
}
```

and the code for batch file is:-

```
@echo off
SET x=
SET x=%x%%1
ECHO %x%
PAUSE
```

save this file as batch.bat and run the c program.
the output just displayed "a" not the value of a("hello sir")
and i want it to display "hello sir"
pleas try and answer as fast as possible.:-)

Comment: Nothing about that `main` is remotely standard compliant (well, besides the name).

Comment: Maybe something like `system("batch.bat " + a);` however I'm not sure about [`system()` function in `C/C++`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/systm.htm)

Comment: This was 3 years ago, i'm embarrassed that i asked such a trivial thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(char **arg)
{
  char cmd[20]="batch.bat ";
  strncat(cmd,argv[1],sizeof(cmd)-strlen(cmd)-1);
  system(cmd);
}
```